# Soffice convert-to pdf with comments

Tags: php, pdf, libreoffice, soffice

I use the command

> soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export myfile

to convert an .odt document to a pdf file, directly in a php file.

In my document I have inserted comments, and after the convertion this comments doesn't appeared. I want them to appear, how can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible. Maybe some different `infilter` or save the comments as part of the document itself before exporting.

Comment: Save the comments is'nt a good solution because I need to know at which line the comments was...
I don't know if I can use infilter because I don't necessarily know the input type of the file. Sometimes is .odt and some other times .docx